# Symfony 3.4: Set multiple properties for entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I can create a new entity and add its data like this:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('Abc');
$foo->setYear('1994');
```

This is using the setter methods that I've defined in my entity class.

However, let's assume that I have this array:

```
$array = array('name' => 'Abc', 'year' => '1994');
```

Is there a way for me to do this:

```
$foo->setData($data);
```

Ideally all the individual array entries should be added to the entity, just like in my first example where I did it manually.

Comment: You could try doing this with the [serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object) component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's ugly but, in the foo class:

```
function setData(array $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

this obivously circumvents the setter logic, so

```
function setData(array $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $func = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
        $this->$func($value);
    }
}
```

you might even write some global

```
function setDataOnObject(array $data, object $object) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $func = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
        $object->$func($value);
    }
}
```

this obviously all requires, that the setters actually exist...

you could also use the [serializer component](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object) as enricog suggested in their comment. Or you could use the property access component, which will by itself find the right setters or adders.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, actually, I figured I can easily add it myself and that's probably why Symfony doesn't provide anything like that out of the box. Just add the following method to the entity class:

```
public function setData($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't be sure what type of data you are setting to the members. By using the setters you can be sure because of type hinting. If you have `setName(string $name)` and use `$foo->setName(1)` PHP will throw an exception. With your method it won't. Use the serializer component or the second example of Jakumi

Comment: @jrswgtr I agree with your essential point, but your example is unfortunate, because `1` would probably be auto-cast to `"1"`. ;o) unless strict? I don't know.

Comment: @Jakumi I guess You're right :-). If I used an `array` instead of an `int` it would be a valid example. However, an array would make less sense as a property of an object. But anyway, I'm glad my point came across.